# mySQL Clearing a database once a month

Tags: mysql

I currently have a database that I need to be cleared on the 1st of every month, I would also like it to output this query into a file before doing that:

```
$con,"SELECT * FROM `Totals` ORDER BY amount desc LIMIT 10"
```

After that I need all "amounts" reset to 0.

I have root access, but i'm unsure if I should CRON or mySQL events and i'm very new to mySQL so i'm not sure how to make it output that query into a file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SELECT INTO OUTFILE

```
SELECT *  INTO OUTFILE '/your_dir/your_filename.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM `Totals` ORDER BY amount desc LIMIT 10;
```

Be careful with the quote for inside a PHP string

see musql doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0):

So set `CRON` to execute your PHP(python etc) file every 1st day of month. In that file execute your `SQL` queries(first query for saving and then for clearing). By using PHP you can simply create `directories` and `files`.